# Empty CSV file when using Export-CSV from script executed by Scheduled Task

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to pull data out of FIM/MIM.  I've been able to create a script that gathers all relevant user information and then I've exported that to a CSV file.

Everything runs perfect when I execute the script interactively (clicking on the .ps1 file or executing the .ps1 file from a batch file). The problem arises when I try to execute the script via Scheduled Task. It creates the file but the file has no data.

Based on a comparison of the script speed when running interactively vs scheduled task, the scheduled task takes less time. This makes me think that the FIM export is running to an error or unable to complete.  It then attempts to export the contents of an empty array to a .csv file.

**Here is my code:**

```
set-variable -name URI -value "http://localhost:5725/resourcemanagementservice' " -option constant
set-variable -name CSV -value "C:\Scripts\Script_Output\FIMUsersExport.csv" -option constant

clear

#Add FIMAutomation Snapin if not already loaded
If (@(Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "FIMAutomation" }).count -eq 0) { Add-PSSnapin FIMAutomation }

#Add FTE filters
$WFDFilter = "/WorkflowDefinition[DisplayName='_Employee Type FTE']"
$curObjectWFD = export-fimconfig -uri $URI –onlyBaseResources -customconfig ($WFDFilter) -ErrorVariable Err -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$WFDObjectID = (($curObjectWFD.ResourceManagementObject.ResourceManagementAttributes | Where-Object { $_.AttributeName -eq "ObjectID" }).value).split(":")[2]
$Filter = "/Person"
$curObject = export-fimconfig -uri $URI –onlyBaseResources -customconfig ($Filter) -ErrorVariable Err -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

[array]$users = $null
foreach ($Object in $curObject)
{
    $ResetPass = New-Object PSObject
    $UserDisplayName = (($Object.ResourceManagementObject.ResourceManagementAttributes | Where-Object { $_.AttributeName -eq "DisplayName" }).Value)
    $UserFirstName = (($Object.ResourceManagementObject.ResourceManagementAttributes | Where-Object { $_.AttributeName -eq "FirstName" }).Value)
    $UserLastName = (($Object.ResourceManagementObject.ResourceManagementAttributes | Where-Object { $_.AttributeName -eq "LastName" }).Value)
    $UserEmail = (($Object.ResourceManagementObject.ResourceManagementAttributes | Where-Object { $_.AttributeName -eq "Email" }).Value)
    $UserMobilePhone = (($Object.ResourceManagementObject.ResourceManagementAttributes | Where-Object { $_.AttributeName -eq "msidmOneTimePasswordMobilePhone" }).Value)
    $UserPFPosNum = (($Object.ResourceManagementObject.ResourceManagementAttributes | Where-Object { $_.AttributeName -eq "pfposNum" }).Value)
    $UserPFSupposNum = (($Object.ResourceManagementObject.ResourceManagementAttributes | Where-Object { $_.AttributeName -eq "pfsupposNum" }).Value)
    $UserOfficePhone = (($Object.ResourceManagementObject.ResourceManagementAttributes | Where-Object { $_.AttributeName -eq "OfficePhone" }).Value)
    $ResetPass | Add-Member NoteProperty "DisplayName" $UserDisplayName
    $ResetPass | Add-Member NoteProperty "FirstName" $UserFirstName
    $ResetPass | Add-Member NoteProperty "LastName" $UserLastName
    $ResetPass | Add-Member NoteProperty "Email" $UserEmail
    $ResetPass | Add-Member NoteProperty "MobilePhone" $UserMobilePhone
    $ResetPass | Add-Member NoteProperty "OfficePhone" $UserOfficePhone
    $ResetPass | Add-Member NoteProperty "PFPosNum" $UserPFPosNum
    $ResetPass | Add-Member NoteProperty "pfsupposNum" $UserPFSupposNum

    $Users += $ResetPass
}

$AHCAUsers = $users | Where-Object{$_.Email -like "*@ahca.myflorida.com"} | Export-Csv -Path $CSV -NoTypeInformation
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that the scheduled task isn't running with enough rights. Try configuring it to run as your user account to see if that makes a difference.

You could also add `Start-Transcript` at the start of your script (and `Stop-Transcript` at the end) which will log all the output of the script to a text file (including error messages) so you can see what is occurring when its running as a scheduled task.

Comment: Awesome. Your tip worked.  I was really skeptical because both accounts are domain admins but there must be something different.  When I run the account under my credentials it seems to work fine, but not with the account that I set up.  I can figure that part out easy enough. Thanks very much for your help and quick response.

Comment: It looks like this came down to FIM/MIM permissions and not just AD permissions.  I had to manually add the service account to the administrators set under FIM/MIM administration via the GUI.